# I have create spring maven project for the first time css,js,images are not loading i have tried all solutions given here still not working

Tags: javascript, css, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have create spring maven project for the first time, and my css,js, images are not loading i have tried all the solutions given here still its not working.

**My directory structure is shown in image:**

[image]

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.niit.musicstore" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**index.jsp**

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<html>
<title>Home</title>
<%-- <meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="./resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" />
<script src="<c:url value="./resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="./resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="./resources/css/styles.css" />" /> --%>
    <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
<body>



    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Music is here</h4>
                    <p>Feel the music and buy your choice you have all the options
                        here!!</p>
                </div>
                <!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div>
            <!-- end item -->

            <div class="item" id="slide2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Songs are here</h4>
                    <p>Listen the song and buy your choice you have all the options
                        here!!</p>
                </div>
                <!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div>
            <!-- end item -->

            <div class="item" id="slide3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Life is happy with songs</h4>
                    <p>Feel the music,Listen the song and buy your choice you have
                        all the options here!!!</p>
                </div>
                <!-- end carousel-caption -->
            </div>
            <!-- end item -->
        </div>
        <!-- end carousel-inner -->

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span
            class="icon-prev"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control"
            data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
    </div>
    <!-- end myCarousel -->


    <div class="row" id="features">

        <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
            <img src="<c:url value="./../resources/images/tabla.png" />" alt="
                MusicHub" class="img-circle">
            <h3>Tabla</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4 feature" id="middle-slide">
            <img src="<c:url value="./../resources/images/sitar.png" />" alt="
                MusicHub" class="img-circle">
            <h3>Sitar</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4 feature" id="last-slide">
            <img src="<c:url value="./../resources/images/flute1.png" />" alt="MusicHub"
                class="img-circle">
            <h3>Flute</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval : 6000
        })
    </script>

    <%-- <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%> --%>

</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.niit.musicstore</groupId>
  <artifactId>musicstore</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>musicstore Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>musicstore</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**This is the output:**

[image: this is the output]

Comment: Can you check in browser console and let us know what are the urls failing for CSS and JS? It will give an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add this code to your spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

2) You don't map your resources correctly with `<c:url>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" >
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css" />" >
```

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
after adding this line my project is running!! thank you!

Comment: If it helped you then accept and upvote it (when it's possible).

Comment: If I'm not using XML for configuration? I'm doing it programmatically.

Comment: @BrunoFreitas It's better but if you know how to translate programmatic code to xml then it's the best